# how to show log in google-app-engine's log window 

Tags: google-app-engine, localhost, logging, show

i can use firepython to show log to firebug,

but  how to show log in the localhost's  log window ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if it is python:

```
import logging

class yourHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  .....

  def get(self):
    .....

    # place this anywhere you want GAE log to show up in console
    logging.info("Something happen here, the value is " + variable_name)

  .....
```

Hopefully it helps.